# Null pointer exception after opening chrome browser (Selenium)

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I hope you all are doing fine.

Could you please help me in fixing this null pointer issue? I'm building a new Selenium framework in my company.
As mentioned below, I'm calling a method "StartBrowser()" in base class from browser class. My code is executing properly until "StartBrowser()" but after that, it's throwing null pointer exception.

Thank you so much in advance.

```
{
public WebDriver driver;

public WebDriver StartBrowser() throws IOException
{
    Properties prop=new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\java\\config\\config.properties");
    prop.load(fis);
    String browserName=prop.getProperty("browser");
    String LADSurl=prop.getProperty("LADSurl");
    String GADSurl=prop.getProperty("GADSurl");
    String chromeDriverPath=prop.getProperty("ChromeDriverPath");
    System.out.println(browserName);
    
    if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
    }
    else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
    {   
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    return driver;
}
```

}

```
public class Base {
public static WebDriver driver;
BrowserFactory browser;
public static Properties prop;
public static String LADSurl;
public static String GADSurl;


enter code here

public static void setupPropertiesFile() throws IOException {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
            System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\main\\java\\config\\config.properties");
    prop.load(fis);
    String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");
    String LADSurl = prop.getProperty("LADSurl");
    String GADSurl = prop.getProperty("GADSurl");
    String chromeDriverPath = prop.getProperty("ChromeDriverPath");
}
public static void OpenApplication(String environment) throws IOException {
    BrowserFactory browser=new BrowserFactory();
    browser.StartBrowser();
    if (environment.equalsIgnoreCase("LADS")) {
        driver.get("www.google.com"); // Local ADS URL
    } else if (environment.equalsIgnoreCase("GADS")) {
        driver.get(GADSurl); // Global ADS URL
    }
```

}

Console error:
Jul 26, 2020 1:49:05 PM cucumber.api.cli.Main run
WARNING: You are using deprecated Main class. Please use io.cucumber.core.cli.Main

Scenario: Create Student                                # src/test/resources/Features/CreateUsers.feature:3
chrome
Starting ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30 (48b3e868b4cc0aa7e8149519690b6f6949e110a8-refs/branch-heads/4147@{#310}) on port 47410
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Jul 26, 2020 1:49:09 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Given User is on New User page                        # stepDefinitions.CreateUserSteps.user_is_on_new_user_page()
java.lang.NullPointerException
at utils.Base.OpenApplication(Base.java:39)
at stepDefinitions.CreateUserSteps.user_is_on_new_user_page(CreateUserSteps.java:38)
at âœ½.User is on New User page(file:///C:/Users/rgorilla/eclipse-workspace/ESA/src/test/resources/Features/CreateUsers.feature:4)

When User provide student information click Save User # stepDefinitions.CreateUserSteps.user_provide_student_information_click_save_user()
Then Validate user is created successfully            # stepDefinitions.CreateUserSteps.validate_user_is_created_successfully()

Comment: You need to show the complete stack trace of the null pointer exception.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. I have just added console error. Is this what you were expecting? Sorry if it is not, this is my first question on this website. Please advice.

Comment: The field `driver` in `Base` does not seem to get assigned to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your base class, driver instance is null because you are not assigning it.

add following in your openApplication() method

```
driver = browser.StartBrowser();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Null point exception happening because of driver instance .In your automation framework have more pages so every pages should handled by same driver instance otherwise you will get null point exception 

Plese change your code to  **static WebDriver driver**; from public WebDriver driver;
```